# How to enable the back button for Android?

Tags: android

How to enable the back button during the phone call for Android?

Comment: What do you want the back button to do?

Answer (score 0):

Override this  method  on what ever screen u want to handle the back button.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```